# Can any body share me java code to make a one Rest api call to IBM BPM Cloud

Tags: rest, cloud, call, business-process-management

Can any body share a java client code which makes a Rest calls to IBM Cloud BPM. Basically I want to know how to authenticate IBM Cloud BPM.

I tried the following code but it is not working

```
String user_info_url="https://ustrial01.bpm.ibmcloud.com/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/user/current?includeInternalMemberships=true&parts=all";

logger.info("user_info_url :" + user_info_url);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(user_info_url);

String authData = "rajesh.kohir123@gmail.com" + ":" + "password";

String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(authData .getBytes());

get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

get.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

HttpResponse cgResponse = client.execute(get); 

if(cgResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {

logger.info("IBM Rest call failed");

}

if(cgResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

logger.info("IBM Rest call Succeded");

String content = EntityUtils.toString(cgResponse.getEntity());

logger.info(content);

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
I ran your code and just made the changes in URL. It worked. I hope this helps you.

Following is the URL I used to execute an exposed service :

https://vhost031.bpm.ibmcloud.com/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/service/OMS@Greetings

I used the following code to add the parameters :

String parameters = "{'name':'pramod'}";

URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://vhost031.bpm.ibmcloud.com/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/service/OMS@Greetings");

List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "start"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("params", parameters));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("createTask", "false"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parts", "all"));

builder.setParameters(nameValuePairs);

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(builder.build());
```

Comment: Hi Pramod,                                                                                                                                     
Thank u very much for reply.But my rest service is located at                                                               https://ustrial01.bpm.ibmcloud.com/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/user/current?includeInternalMemberships=true&parts=all, I want to get Current logined in user info.This service "/user/current?includeInternalMemberships=true&parts=all" is provided by IBM Cloud BPM. So first I need to login into the server.

Answer (score 0):

Download the download.zip form the [post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1202_olivieri/1202_olivieri.html).

Look at the SampleBPDProcessTests.java - Line no 103

```
JSONObject results = bpmClient.runBPD(BPD_ID, PROCESS_APP_ID, bpdArgs);
```

The actual Java Code for Rest call is available as part of "bpm-rest-client.jar"

Try this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Java code to start a process:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://ustrial03.bpm.ibmcloud.com:443/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/process? 
 processAppId=3u092jr02j-djaodaj.u092302c166c1&bpdId=25.jklaklaa-539a-4150- 
 b63e-9ef94e96e521&action=start")
.put(null)
.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic YXJrYX24223232hQGRlbG9pdHRlLmNvbTpkZWZjb240QA==")
.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
.addHeader("Postman-Token", "f46c1525-7a75-954c-9265-bb2b21a57f16")
.build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

A full explanation of REST integration with BPM Cloud can be found in my answer at:
[How to run IBM BPM Rest api call from Post man client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694092/how-to-run-ibm-bpm-rest-api-call-from-post-man-client#51572095)